# Why is my car overheating in the winter?

Tags: coolant, overheating, acura

I am a novice when it comes to cars but I am trying to learn. Here is what is going on.

Car 97 Acura Cl
I replaced the radiator in the summertime and forgot to put coolant back in the system. 
After the temperatures got below freezing and my car started to run a little rough I realized I had forgotten and added a 50/50 mix immediately.

When i would start my car the engine would auto/ghost rev itself [VIDEO HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jt5onWc00iCSkDg-pWMcRWYKDnq7zRPQNA/view?usp=sharing) and [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19GrpqxWjSaAlmJ4dkdYheqIAI4TAEf1t-w/view?usp=sharing)

Some additional things:

-The car will drive for about 5 miles before it overheats. 
-The gas petal sticks when I first try to accelerate
-When engine is idle the RPMs doesn't go back to zero. 
-The ghost revving **doesn't** happen everytime I start the car.

I have a feeling the coolant is not circulating through the radiator/engine. Is there a way to tell  ?

Thank you for your help in advance. Trying to learn.

Comment: Did you check the thermostat when you replaced the radiator? Are you leaking water / coolant?

Comment: hi there. I think I need to burp the coolant. I am having issues finding the bleeder bolt though... it's a acura cl 97

Comment: I cant wrap my head around someone having the skills to replace a radiator and forgetting to fill it. There is absolutely no way you drove for more than five minutes without coolant. Are you sure it was the radiator you replaced??

Comment: ha. yes my ex replaced it for me. I just watched and learned. Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: You couldn't have driven the car with no coolant. Maybe it didn't have enough coolant, but without your engine would have overheated quickly.

Comment: I agree that you could not have driven much without coolant. It would have overheated everytime you drove it. Did you mean to say there was only water in the system and not antifreeze? If so, it sounds like the water has frozen and is blocking the passages, or worse, damaged your engine. There just isn't enough information here to tell.

Comment: I was driving it and all it had was water in it. Then temps feel and I remembered and put 50/50 in it right away. I can drive the car about 5 miles before it over heats. I read that it could be because there is air in the system and I need to "burp it" however I am having trouble finding the bleeding bolt.

Comment: Two things... Why was the radiator replaced?  Secondly, you can take the radiator cap off and start the car, and watch the water level... Take note when the water starts to flow (around) as soon as the car is warm...If it does not flow, your thermostat could be blocked / broken / not working.  Thermostats are cheap but often broken out of the box.  They can be tested in the kitchen :)

Comment: You should be able to let any air out simply by removing the radiator cap (when cold), and then running the car until warm.  Then don't forget to put the cap back on if you start to drive anywhere....But cap can stay off for a long time while you watch it, examine stuff etc when idling...

Comment: Thanks so much for the replies. The vehicle was constantly overheating, and my ex had told me the radiator needed to be replaced. Once he did that (during the summer) everything was running great. Then once it got cold the car started acting up again. I will check the thermostat...any tips on how to do this?

Comment: If I purchase an obd2 scanner would that tell me if it was the thermostat for sure?